# Efficient way to get N rows order by complex expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, sql-order-by, limit

I have a table `line_item { id: int, price: decimal, quantity: int, [other:...] }`. This table is very huge, approx. 28 million rows. Now I want to get top 1000 rows `order by f(price, quantity, [other...])`, `f` is a arbitrary function. What is the best way to do that?

I thought 2 solutions:

1. Use `order by` and `limit`. This way may be slow because I think MySQL calculates result of `f` for every row then sorts them.
2. Create new column to store result of function `f`. This way is not good for scalability because maybe I want to use multiple function `f` (`f1`, `f2`...) in different context.

I really hope there is third solution which is better than them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry, this is a negative answer, but that's life.)

If you will accept the "best solution" being only twice as fast as what you have experienced, then Accept @Zsuzsa's.

I'm here to tell you that it cannot be optimized without doing something about f(...).  Here's why:

The optimizer sees no WHERE clause, but sees an ORDER BY with an expression.  So, it realizes that the only way to evaluate the query is to do a "table scan" (that is, read *all* the rows), evaluate the function for each row, save the results in a tmp table (with 28M rows), sort that tmp table, and deliver 1000 rows.

Can *any* of that function be copied into the WHERE clause for filtering out some rows?  If so, the tmp table might be smaller.  Or, if you are lucky, perhaps some INDEX can be devised so that it does not have to do a full table scan.

Are you modifying all the rows?  Or is this sort of a "write only" table?  That is, does a row, once written, never change?  Building on that, can f() pre-computed for all the 'old' rows?  If so, store it somewhere and add an index -- Poof!  Instant results.

Is a common part of f() a test for some date range?  (Big tables often have some kind of date.  Queries on big tables often ask about "recent" items.)  If so, can that be pulled out of f().  Then we can consider PARTITIONing the table by date.  That way, even if nothing else can be optimized in f, "partition pruning" could limit the number of rows to deal with.

Please SHOW CREATE TABLE and discuss whether some of the ideas here might be feasible.

Comment: Yes, f() depends on date value. So store pre-computed values is not a good  way. In big system like stackoverflow, they just compute that value when user requests and they don't care about big questions table?

Comment: A big system like stackoverflow designs its database, and its user expectations, so that it never has to scan 28M rows while the user is waiting.

Comment: How stackoverflow does that? I saw stackoverflow has some sorts like that: sort hot questions, active questions... I think they are more complex than my problem. Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how they do it.  Some guesses:  A column saying how 'hot' questions plus an INDEX starting with that column.  An "active" flag does not make a good INDEX, but a compound INDEX(active, timestamp) would let them say WHERE active ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50 -- very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about another option:

Create a temporary table with only the id and f columns.

Create a second temporary table (temp_table2) and insert the following results in it:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 id, f
FROM temp_table
ORDER BY f
```

This should run faster than the other 2 options you mentioned, because here you have to work only with 2 columns.

At the end you can select the final results by joining this seoncd temporary table to your original table.

```
SELECT line_item.* --or just the columns you need
FROM temp_table2
INNER JOIN line_item
ON temp_table2.id = line_item.id
```

You can also try to execute the 1st option you mentioned, and see if there is any significant performance improvement if using the temporary tables suggested by me.
The use of temporary tables can improve the execution time in many cases, but not all the time - so the best is to try both and see which works better.